# CreateJS increase shadow offsetX with Tween.js

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs, tween.js

I have a simple sprite sheet animation.

```
var data = {
        images: ["public/images/coin.png"],
        frames: {
            width:  343,
            height: 342,
            count:  36,
            regX:   0,
            regY:   0
        },
        animations: {
            stand: [
                35
            ],
            head: [
                0, 35, 'head', 1
            ],
            tail: [
                0, 18, 'coin', 0.8
            ]
        }
    };

    var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
    var animation = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, "head");
```

Here is my shaddow:

```
animation.shadow = new createjs.Shadow("#000000", 9, 2, 10);
```

also I'm scaling and changing position of this sprite sheet animation with, tween.js

```
createjs.Tween.get(animation, { loop: false })
        .to({ scaleX:.7 , scaleY:.7, x: xCoord, y: yCoord}, 1100)
        .to({ scaleX: .3 , scaleY:.3, x: 200, y: 300}, 1100);
```

I want to increase shadow OffsetX during tweenJS animation and then decrease.

How can I achieve that?

Here is working demo:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6t5cc9g/)

Comment: If you are just tweening, you can also tween the shadow at the same time with another tween that targets the Shadow instance. Here is a sample of a shadow tween: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/x3r8cumx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an event listener. The event listener will be called whenever the tween's position changes.
http://createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html

Comment: Ps: You can get the animation's property scaleX in the event listener.If scaleX >= .7 ,increase. otherwise, decrease.

Comment: Also remember that drawing shadows is an extremely expensive operation, so take care when animating them.